# How can I implement boundaries or collisions for this movement style?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, collision

I'm trying to make a simple game and it's working well. The movement is like the movement of a tetris block (instantly, like teleporting) and this is what I want. I don't want smooth movement, I want this movement style.

But there is a problem... When I try to add boundaries or collision for my character and rect, it's not working, but if I write this code it's working only one time and then both the left and the right arrow key don't work anymore.  How can I solve this problem?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

ekranx = 160
ekrany = 310
window = pygame.display.set_mode((ekranx, ekrany))
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,200)
pygame.display.set_caption("TOP")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
ball = pygame.image.load("top.png")


def top(x,y):
    window.blit(ball,(x,y))
top_x = (55)
top_y = (250)
cikis = False
while not cikis:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            cikis = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                #--SOL
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    top_x += -50


                #--SAĞ
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    top_x += 50


    #print(event)
    window.fill(white)
    top(top_x,top_y)
    pygame.draw.rect(window,blue,(5,5,150,300),5)
    if top_x < 6:
        pygame.K_LEFT = False
    if top_x > 104:
        pygame.K_RIGHT = False
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pygame.K_LEFT = False` <-- Don't do that. You're overriding the `pygame.K_LEFT` constant (which is actually an integer `276`) here and that means you can't use it anymore in your program (pygame won't recognize these events anymore).

Just set `top_x` to the minimum or maximum value if the ball moves too far left or right:

```
if top_x < 6:
    top_x = 6
if top_x > 104:
    top_x = 104
```

Comment: thank you so much, skrx. you fixed it!!! im appreciated. thank you a lot!!

Comment: I also recommend to check out how [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s work, if you need collision detection.

Comment: thanks for all your  help. by the way i want to create a start menu(codes same) but i couldnt make it. i tried a lot of ways but i couldnt. how can i make a start menu. it will be a full white screen and start or quit buttons?

Comment: This really belongs in a new question not in the comments and it's also a bit laborious to explain properly, but as a quick and dirty solution you can use another while loop with its own event loop and just blit the buttons. When the user clicks 'start' you break out of the loop and the main game loop will start. For the buttons you can use `pygame.Rects` and see if the mouse position collides with them by using their `collidepoint` method.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to use a [finite state machine like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/), but you'll have to learn how classes and object oriented programming work. Here's a nice tutorial: [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en#section_12). Chapter 13 is about pygame sprites and sprite groups and helps to learn more about classes.

Comment: thank you a lot, skrx. i made everything with your help.